# Save html content of a widget textarea

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have a textarea inside a custom widget that needs to hold some html tags. I've noticed that if I use the `esc_html` or `esc_attr` or `strip_tags` to take the things secure, I  will lost all the html I use. How I can keep the html tags in place, I just need to add an `<i>` tag and `<p>` or `<h>`, `<a>` tags. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wp_kses_post` instead! It will keep all the tags allowed in a post, you can also use `wp_kses` and provide a list of tags and attributes

Comment: Thank you! I will implement it inside my widget code.

Comment: Just a question, with `wp_kses`, can I pass only the tags I want to allow, or I need to specify an array for the attributes for each tag?